# How to calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)} [\ln(5-(x^2+y^2))]\sqrt{y^2-4}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I couldn't find the limit 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)} [\ln(5-(x^2+y^2))]\sqrt{y^2-4}.$$

I tried substituting $x$ and $y$ with polar coordinates but didn't get far. Wolfram says the answer is $0$. 
Thank you.

Comment: @almagest That circle is not in the domain of the function.

Comment: @rogerl Good point. Whether the limit is well-defined needs a little more thought. :)

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not exist. This can be shown by choosing a curve through $(1,2)$, which runs closer and closer to the circle $x^2+y^2 =5$. This way the $\ln$ will pull towards $-\infty$, faster than $\sqrt{y^2-4}$ pulls toward $0$.

Choose
$$ x(y) = \sqrt{5-y^2} - \exp\Big[{-\frac{1}{(y-2)^2}}\Big].$$
Now the limit along this curve is
$$ \lim_{y \to 2+} f(x(y),y).$$

Note that
$$ f(x(y),y) = \ln(5-x^2(y) -y^2) \sqrt{y^2 -4} = $$
$$ \ln\Big(-\exp\Big[{-\frac{2}{(y-2)^2}}\Big] + 2\sqrt{5-y^2}\exp\Big[{-\frac{1}{(y-2)^2}}\Big]\Big) \sqrt{y^2 -4}\leq$$
$$ \ln\Big(2\exp\Big[{-\frac{1}{(y-2)^2}}\Big]\Big) \sqrt{y^2 -4}=$$
$$ \Big( \ln(2) - \frac{1}{(y-2)^2} \Big) \sqrt{y^2 -4} =$$
$$ \Big( \ln(2) \sqrt{y^2 -4}\Big) - \Big(\frac{1}{(y-2)^2}  \sqrt{y^2 -4}\Big).$$

Finally, the first term clearly approaches $0$, whereas the second goes to $-\infty$, as $y\to 2+$.

Answer (score 0):

The limit doesn't exist in the usual calculus sense: Any neighborhood of $(1,2)$ will contain points where $5-(x^2+y^2) < 0,$ rendering $\ln (5-(x^2+y^2))$ undefined.

Comment: The assumption is that only the domain is interesting, the are definitions appropriate for such cases

Comment: @User yes, but those definitions are not "in the usual calculus sense", where I'm referring to calculus as it is taught in the U.S.